# Cordova fullscreen splash screen on Android still shows title bar

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, phonegap-plugins

I am creating a fullscreen app using latest cordova.
I have added the splash screen images and the plugin for it. And also in the config.xml, the preference to launch the app in fullscreen

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />    
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
```

When running the app, the splash screen shows up, but the problem is that the app **still shows the title bar** on top, until the app finishes showing the splash screen, where the app finally goes into true full screen.

Is there a way/flag/mod to make the **fullscreen work correctly while splash screen is displayed**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to show a full screen splash is by putting this line in your manifest under activity tag

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: Getting this error: `AAPT: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`

Answer (score 13):

Del's answer definitely solves the problem, but it is problematic if you have the `platforms` directory ignored (it *is* derived content after all).

Fortunately, starting with `cordova@6.4.0` you can use [`<edit-config>`](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config) in `config.xml` too:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget ... xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge"
                 target="/manifest/application/activity">
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    </edit-config>
    ...
</widget>
```

This will ensure that `AndroidManifest.xml` will get updated whenever it is generated. Mind the additional XML Namespace for Android.

Comment: Getting this error: `AAPT: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`

Comment: @iONinja Did you add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to your `<widget>`?

Comment: Great! Works well.