# Phonegap Cordova - Black status bar on bottom after fullscreen

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, config, statusbar

I've been having this issue for as long as I can remember. I thought it might have just been from my phone or the emulation, but after publishing my app I still see this black rectangle at the bottom of screen, which looks like the status bar.

This happens after I have this in my config.xml

```
<preference name="android-build-tool"      value="gradle"   />   
<preference name="Fullscreen"              value="true"     />
<preference name="Orientation"             value="portrait" />
```

***Screenshot:***

[image]

***UPDATE***

I noticed the bottom black bar goes away if I **MINIMIZE** the game and click it right back up (weird).

I tried creating a new project and same thing happens once I put the full screen preference in config.xml.

It seems like the top bar transfers to the bottom >_>

Comment: Can you provide details on cordova versions, android versions any frameworks etc?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @coderama It may sound crazy but can you try setting proper size launch iamges and check once as this causes issue in iOS

Comment: This specifically happens to me in Android. I haven't gotten around to testing IOS yet. I added bounty to this question and started another question summarizing my efforts here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768186/android-phonegap-compilations-adds-bar-at-the-bottom-of-app-that-should-not-be-t ... I can't be the only one stick on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the problem is with defining the dimensions of the canvas. Solved this a while ago so I'm not sure if this is what fixed it:

```
var c  = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx  = c.getContext("2d");
var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1; // get pixel ratio of device
c.width = window.screen.width * pixelRatio;
c.height = window.screen.height * pixelRatio;
c.style.width = window.screen.width + 'px';
c.style.height = window.screen.height + 'px';
```

Also try deleting your index.css file

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this code? What is canvas1? The first div in which viewable info is shown?

Comment: I get " c.getContext is not a function".

Comment: `canvas1` is the id of the canvas I defined in my HTML. Instead of `canvas1`, put in the id of your canvas

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the very same issue using only `<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />` in my `config.xml`.

I initially thought of the Android status bar, but had some research on that topic and now got a very strong believe, that this issue comes from some other Android system UI not being hidden until the Cordova wrapper finished init, resulting in a wrong calculated size for the wrapper.

After a long search and trying out nearly everything you also mentioned, I stumbled upon a plugin:

[cordova-plugin-fullscreen](https://github.com/mesmotronic/cordova-plugin-fullscreen)

I'm now using this in the config.xml

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleInstance" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="true" />
```

And this directly in first play of the method triggered on `deviceready`

```
if (AndroidFullScreen) {
    // Extend your app underneath the status bar (Android 4.4+ only)
    AndroidFullScreen.showUnderStatusBar();

    // Extend your app underneath the system UI (Android 4.4+ only)
    AndroidFullScreen.showUnderSystemUI();

    // Hide system UI and keep it hidden (Android 4.4+ only)
    AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode();
}
```

Tested so far with Android 6.0, 5.0.1 with hardware navigation and software navigation devices. Maybe that could help you aswell.

Comment: Fullscreen plugin worked for me, but with another function on deviceready


  `if (window.AndroidFullScreen) {
    window.AndroidFullScreen.showSystemUI();
    window.AndroidFullScreen.immersiveMode();
  }`

Android 4.4.2

Comment: @zamuka's solution worked for me on 6.0 Samsung j5, but not in onDeviceReady - worked fine a little later into the loading process using setTimeout

Answer (score 2):

You can use cordova hooks to apply the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` fix to AndroidManifest.xml or you can use `<edit-config>` in `config.xml` starting with `cordova@6.4.0`:

`<widget ... xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge"
                 target="/manifest/application/activity">
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    </edit-config>
    ...
</widget>`

Source: [Cordova fullscreen splash screen on Android still shows title bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315998/cordova-fullscreen-splash-screen-on-android-still-shows-title-bar/40872424#40872424)

Answer (score 1):

By default the DOM will only fill the space required to render its contents. Setting an element `height:100%;` is setting it's height relative to its parent element's height. If you want the visible element to be the height of the screen, you can set the element `height:1vh;` which is the height of your screen. This might cause some unexpected scrolling behavior though, so another method is to set all the parent elements `height:100%;`, starting with the html document.
in css:

```
html, body, ... other parent elements ... {
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: 1vh would mean 1 percent of the screen height. To actually fit the whole screen height, it would be 100vh ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to poll the display/canvas size for changes.

That black band looks like it's about the same size as the system's top status bar, so I suspect that your app is receiving the viewport size just before the status bar is removed/animated by the system.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but only happening sometimes. I tried the whole day fixing this issue and am on the same opinion, that it is Cordova requesting the height before Android removes the bar, resulting in a too small rendering canvas. Did you already find any solution for that?

Comment: Found a solution working for me, see my answer for detail.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Using the cordova status bar plugin fixed it for me:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-statusbar/index.html#installation

Install the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

Remove the fullscreen setting in config.xml and add the plugin instead:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.2" />
```

Call the StatusBar.hide() to hide the status bar in JavaScript. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
        StatusBar.hide();
    }, false);
});
```

[Camparison Screenshot - Before and After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkH9r.jpg)

Comment: The jQuery document ready bit isn't necessary, but otherwise this works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem. It happens mostly in landscape mode for me.
I have a samsung s7 and a samsung tab2.
on the s7 it happens once over 20 times
on the tab2 it happens all the time.
I can detect when something is wrong by checking the body height versus the screenheight ( in correlation with the pixel ratio )

I applied the AndroidFullScreen and the  trick
So far everything is fixed on the tablet, no more dark bar at the bottom. But for the s7 I still have this issue.
The s7 has a pixel ratio of 4 the tab2 the pixel ratio is 1